# thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code = 1, address = 0x7fff00000001)

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to pass an array to a function that sums up all the elements in the array, but I get a bad access error at the line `sum+=a[i];` how can i fix this? Here is the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int sum(int*, int);

int main() {

@autoreleasepool {

    int size = 0;
    int a[size];
    int x;

    NSLog(@"Enter a size for the array ");
    scanf("%i", &size);

    NSLog(@"Enter %i numbers to populate the array ", size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf("%i", &a[i]);
    }

    x = sum(a, size);

    NSLog(@"The sum of the array is %i ", x);    
}

return 0;

}

int sum(int *a, int n) {

int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    sum += a[i];
}
return sum;
}
```

Comment: @Josh - why would you pull the `objective-c` tag in favor of `C`? this is clearly `objective-c` code

Comment: Not really, @Mike -- the problem itself is completely based in C's memory management. The only thing that requires the ObjC runtime is the `@autoreleasepool`, which isn't doing anything anyways because no ObjC objects are being put into it. It has to be compiled as ObjC because of the literal `NSString`s, but those have no bearing on the actual issue or its solution. Both those things could be removed without affecting the compileability of this code, and the problem would be the same, and squarely in C's domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your array is 0 in size. Writing / Reading from a[i] may / may not crash as it's behavior is undefined.

Instead of

```
int size = 0;
int a[size];
int x;

NSLog(@"Enter a size for the array ");
scanf("%i", &size);
```

you should do this instead:

```
int size = 0;
int *a;
int x;

NSLog(@"Enter a size for the array ");
scanf("%i", &size);

a = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

By dynamically allocate the array `a`, your program should no longer crash.

And after we use `malloc`, we have to free it when we don't need it anymore. Put this before `return 0;`

```
free(a);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it. I get this error frequently when coding in Xcode  never knew what was causing it.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined an array of size 0.  Since an array is a block of memory, and in this case a block of "no" memory, you cannot store anything into it.

You can use malloc/free as indicated in @Owen's answer.  C99 also added the ability to declare arrays on the stack (so-called VLA, Variable Length Arrays).  This saves you using malloc/free but leaves you at risk of using up all your stack space.  For values which you know for a fact will be constrained, a VLA might make sense:

```
int size;
NSLog(@"Enter a size for the array ");
scanf("%i", &size);

int arr[size];

....
```

Note that in C89/C90/ANSI you would not be able to do that, since the size of an array must be a compile-time constant.

Comment: Thanks!!! All help is appreciated. Im teaching myself objective C coming from C++ so im sure ill have plenty more questions.